# how to select mulitple different text/content using regular expression

Tags: replace, expression, notepad++

I have almost 1 milllon line of xml data, I want to replace more than 10 different content with almost same but some different text.
See example below

```
<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[5590]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>slide_template</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[default]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_jetpack_related_posts_cache</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:0:{}]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>vibe_author</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[H]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>vibe_prev_next</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[H]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
```

suppose I want to replace

```
<wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>vibe_author
```

and or

```
vibe_prev_next</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[H]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
```

I apply this code:

```
(<wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>)vibe_author|vibe_prev_next.*?</wp:postmeta>
```

But it's only select

```
<wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>vibe_author
```

or

```
vibe_prev_next</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[H]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
```

How can I select

```
<wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>vibe_author</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[H]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
```

and

```
<wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>vibe_prev_next</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[H]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
```

at one time?

Answer (score 0):

You were close but you put the alternation `|` in the top level of the expression.

It should have been applied to a group of the values you need to alternate between e.g. `(vibe_author|vibe_prev_next)` try using this expression:

```
(?s)<wp:postmeta>\s*<wp:meta_key>(?:vibe_author|vibe_prev_next).*?</wp:postmeta>
```

Comment: have you got the search mode set to Regular Expression? Also what version of notepad++ are you using?

Comment: yes, of course I check regex and match new line radio button